# Google Distance Matrix Api: travel time with traffic

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the travel time with traffic between 2 sets of lat/long coordinates. I can call the Google Distance Matrix API, but I am only getting travel time **without** traffic. The `API notes` which I have read say to use a parameter called departure_time. Here is the excerpt:

> *departure_time specifies the desired time of departure as seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. The departure time may be specified by Maps for Business customers for to specify the departure_time to receive trip duration considering current traffic conditions. The departure_time must be set to within a few minutes of the current time.*

I found this website to give me that time: epochconverter

However I am still getting the same travel time every time. Here is a sample request, the departure_time parameter would need to be updated (not that it matters).

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?units=imperial&departure_time=1408046331&origins=37.407585,-122.145287&destinations=37.482890,-122.150235

15 minutes is always returned.

Using "maps dot google dot com" a travel time of 19 mins is returned when traffic is taken into account.

If anyone can help me get the travel time with traffic from the Distance Matrix API, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you a _Maps for Business_ customer?  It looks like it is only available to Business accounts and not the free tier.

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 5):

No need for business license, just need an API key from project on https://console.developers.google.com/ with Google distance Matrix enabled.
For results as on google map use traffic_model with values pessimistic,optimistic and do keep in mind "The departure_time must be set to within a few minutes of the current time" without that it will always return 15 minutes.

Comment: Any reason this was downvoted? Is this incorrect? Reading over the docs, I didn't come across a mention that this was currently still for business customers.

Comment: The accurate result of traffic module of google distance matrix is only available to " Google Maps APIs Premium Plan customers" as from link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_results

Comment: This was the problem for me, I had to explicitly add `departure_time=now` to my query string in order to get results that took traffic into account.

Answer (score 3):

That feature appears to only be available to Maps for Business customers, according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#usage_limits_and_requirements).

Answer (score 3):

Even with business licence you can only query departure_time 5 minutes from now if you're using traveling mode is driving

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Answer (score 3):

According to the google docs "departure_time" can only be used if "mode"(travel mode) is set to "Driving"(which is the default travelMode) and an Api KEY is included in your request.
There is also an optional parameter "trafficModel".
Here is an example url with proper parameters.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=40.6655101,-73.89188969999998&destinations=40.598566%2C-73.7527626&mode=driving&departure_time=now&traffic_model=optimistic&key=YOUR_API_KEY

To use distance matrix api as javascript code use it as mentioned in this doc.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix

**Imp:**There are many limitations with this API. Most of the features are available only for premium users.Read the above doc carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Please try with below code.

```
var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(detectedLatitude,detectedLongitude);       
var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(latitudeVal,langtitudeVal);
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    var DrivingOptions = {
    departureTime: date,
    trafficModel: 'pessimistic'
    };

    service.getDistanceMatrix(
      {
        origins: [origin],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        drivingOptions : DrivingOptions,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        durationInTraffic: true,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
      }, response_data);function response_data(responseDis, status) {
  if (status !== google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK || status != "OK"){
    console.log('Error:', status);
    // OR
    alert(status);
  }else{
       alert(responseDis.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text);
  }});
```

Please refer this document [click here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)

Answer (score 1):

This API can solve your problem - [https://distancematrix.ai/dev](https://distancematrix.ai/dev?utm_source=sflow&utm_medium=answer&utm_campaign=dev_7)

It takes into consideration the traffic conditions, road constructions, and other restrictions when calculating travel time. And if you were using Google's API before for you will be easy, because you don't need to rewrite code.

Regarding the departure time, you will find the following in the documentation:

"departure_time — a desired time of the departure. You can specify the time as an integer in seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970, UTC. Alternatively, you can specify a value of now, which sets the departure time to the current time (correct to the nearest second). If neither time is specified, the departure_time defaults to now (that is, the departure time defaults to the current time). The departure_time must be set to the current time or some time in the future. It cannot be in the past. Results for a given request may vary over time due to the changes in the road network, updated average traffic conditions, and the distributed nature of the service. Results may also vary between nearly-equivalent routes at any time or frequency."

Follow these recommendations, and you won't have this problem. Besides, you can easily contact the developers and ask any questions concerning your situation.

Disclaimer: I work at a company that creates this API.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using golang client, set DepartureTime to "now" in the input parameter DirectionsRequest of the Directions func.